# how to add an icon inside the vue child component?

Tags: css, vue.js, import, sass, vuejs2

Expecting to have in the template the image both ways: with img tag and as a backgournd. None of it works, even though the path to the icon is correct.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fsg2l2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader.vue,src%2Frouter%2Findex.js,src%2Fviews%2FHome.vue,src%2Fviews%2FShops.vue,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fassets%2Ficons%2Fvkontakte-header.svg

```js
<div>
  <a href="#" class="icon"
    >
    <img src="../assets/icons/icon.svg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>

<styles>
.icon {
    background: url(../assets/icons/icon.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
</styles
```

Comment: Share your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

your assets folder is not in the public folder, the path is relative to the index.html which is located in the public folder

Comment: No, it still not works